# Meteor helper for Visual Studio Code: what is a meteor project directory

Tags: meteor, visual-studio-code

I am trying to use Visual Studio Code as an alternative to Webstorm to edit and debug a toy Meteor app. After installing the MeteorHelper extension which is announced as provided "Meteor CLI integration into VSCode" and try to run any Meteor command I get the error msg: 
"X is not a meteor project directory, check your workspace definition".

I don't know whether the problem is the LOCATION of my directory X, or its CONTENT (something is missing?). I changed the meteorhelper.relativeProjectPath string in the settings.json file to various possible values to no avail.

Has anyone out there tried to use VSCode to edit and debug a Meteor app and got that error?

Answer (score 0):

A Meteor project directory is what gets created when using the command:

```
meteor create my-app
```

This command creates a folder that contains your Meteor applications' code. Typically, the directory structure looks something like this:

```
my-app/
  .meteor/
  client/
  imports/
  server/
  package.json
```

The error you're describing would be encountered while attempting to run a project-specific meteor command from outside of a Meteor project. In the above example, I would access the project directory by first entering

```
cd my-app
```

on the command line.

Comment: Thanks. Strangely, the meteor create command is not available in the menu of options provided by the MeteorHelper extension. So I had to create the project using the Windows prompt.